# Business website hosted publicly (for APIs, etc) needs to be accessible ONLY from inside office?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, amazon-ec2, security

Would appreciate your patience with this question; still learning a lot of things.

My Taxi booking start-up has a website (CakePHP) hosted on EC2 (for reliability) which is a ERP of sorts used only by internal employees. This tool also interacts with the Cabs/Taxis' GPS receivers in that these GPS machines send some data to the public server through some APIs which help decide logic for the Booking process. And as we don't have very strong Net on premises, we've kept it all on EC2.

Now, we are increasingly concerned about leaving information (customer data, vehicle info) like this on the public domain and accessible from the internet and outside the premises by a rogue employee. For our implementation, MySQL replication has already been considered with us reading from a local slave, writing to the master and etc. The only issue being, there's no way non-technical employees would know whether the data is new or whether the replication is broken. Also, we'd prefer our servers online as we don't want to invest in physical security for this hardware.

We are thinking of the following:

1. IP address based auth; those belonging to the local NAT would be allowed. Problem is we have a dynamic IP.
2. Computername/MacID based auth; almost no-security once the user finds out. Also, can we read these parameters from Chrome?
3. Storing a list of IP addresses that login and as there are just 6 employees, we'd be able to monitor it for weird IPs. Not scalable or even secure.
4. Hosts file configuration on employee PC and this "host" would be configured on apache2 so directly hitting the IP address would do no good. Again, needs one smart employee.

Do help us out!

Comment: What if you only allowed connections from localhost on the server, and used an ssh tunnel from your office to the server?

Comment: @JeffS I forgot that we considered this! Unfortunately, I was unable to get a persistent SSH tunnel to work on Ubuntu..any links to guides?

Comment: I don't have a particuarly good guide. I'd definitely look into autossh for this. This question in general would probably get a better response on ServerFault

Comment: Will look at that thanks! Have posted on ServerFault as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should look at VPC, its Amazon's virtual private cloud. Its the better option for hosting solutions on EC2 that are private to your enterprise.

it would allow you to create a private network that is only accessible from your computers, with internet facing servers in a seperate subnet.

you have a number if ways of connecting the private subnet to your office, a VPN seems the option here for you (low cost, no special h/w required), see http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/ and http://d36cz9buwru1tt.cloudfront.net/Extend_your_IT_infrastructure_with_Amazon_VPC.pdf

Comment: Thanks, we went ahead with SSH but we're exploring this now!

Answer (score 0):

I considered writing this as a comment but don't have enough rep...

I'm not sure where you are from, but in my region, the cost of a static IP is negligible ($10-$50) a month, which is a drop considering the risk of liability you are facing. Then you can secure the server with usernames and passwords, and check the originating IP also.

You may also be able to setup a computer to scrape something like whatismyip every hour to see if the IP changes and update the IP if it changes.

Comment: Thanks for that..actually our ISP offers it too. But here, for connections like ours, they offer a static for 'inbound' connections. Something like a redirect.